# Why does ahadot+asarot in the print line add up while ahadot1 and asarot1 don't?

Tags: java

```
int ahadot = firstpair % 10;
int asarot = firstpair % 100 / 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter first pair: ");
    int firstpair = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter second pair: ");
    int secondpair = in.nextInt();
    
    int ahadot = firstpair % 10;
    int asarot = firstpair % 100 / 10;
    
    int ahadot1=secondpair % 10;
    int asarot1=secondpair % 100 / 10;

    System.out.println(ahadot + asarot + " , " + asarot1 + ahadot1);
}
```

for example if I enter "35" as the first pair and "52" as the other pair, why does it add up 3 + 5 for the first pair while simply printing the number on the second pair?

Comment: Please consider renaming your variables so the code is easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Type conversion. The first + is treated as (conceptually) +(int, int), the second is +(int, string) which forces a string conversion, and the rest become +(string, int). You can see a simplified example

```
System.out.println(1 + 3 + ", " + 1 + 3);
// 4, 13
```

vs

```
System.out.println((1 + 3) + ", " + (1 + 3));
// 4, 4
```

Easiest solution is to use parenthesis to group, a better option is probably to use

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", ahadot + asarot, ahadot1 + asarot1));
```

This decouples printing from calculating and (imo) is easier to read/maintain.